# HTML if one checkbox checked then others cant

Tags: html

If I check on 'None of above' then else cannot checked. But in my checkbox it can. Any idea to solve this?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td width="100px">1. Cough</td><td width="80px"><input type="hidden" name="cough" value="no"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="cough" value="yes"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100px">2. Sore Throat</td><td width="80px"><input type="hidden" name="sore_throat" value="no"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="sore_throat" value="yes"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100px">3. Fever</td><td width="80px"><input type="hidden" name="fever" value="no"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="fever" value="yes"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100px">4. Flu</td><td width="80px"><input type="hidden" name="flu" value="no"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="flu" value="yes"></td>
<tr>
<td width="230px">5. None of above</td><td width="80px"><input type="hidden" name="none" value="no"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="none" value="yes"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Explain your problem in a more detail

Comment: You mean if "None of above" is checked other checkbox should be disabled ?

Comment: @Vishal Yes..if "None of above" is uncheck then others can be checked.

Comment: About the naming: I would rename "none" to a more speaking id, maybe "no_disease".

Comment: Why you won't use a radiobuttons? They are designed to do just that! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Comment: @Volvox but, can not select multiple diseases !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `querySelectorAll` to find a collection of checkboxes that are NOT the key checkbox ( `none` ) and for each one disable/enable it dependant upon the state of the key checkbox like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',e=>{
  document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"][name="none"]').addEventListener('click',function(e){//find all checkboxes that are NOT the key checkbox
    let col=document.querySelectorAll('input[ type="checkbox" ]:not( [ name="none" ] )');
    col.forEach(chk=>{//iterate through collection
      chk.disabled=this.checked;//disable current checkbox if key is checked and enable if not checked
      if( this.checked )chk.checked=false;//if key checkbox is checked, all others cannot be checked
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="100px">1. Cough</td>
    <td width="80px"><input type="hidden" name="cough" value="no"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="cough" value="yes"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100px">2. Sore Throat</td>
    <td width="80px"><input type="hidden" name="sore_throat" value="no"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="sore_throat" value="yes"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100px">3. Fever</td>
    <td width="80px"><input type="hidden" name="fever" value="no"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="fever" value="yes"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100px">4. Flu</td>
    <td width="80px"><input type="hidden" name="flu" value="no"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="flu" value="yes"></td>
  <tr>
    <td width="230px">5. None of above</td>
    <td width="80px"><input type="hidden" name="none" value="no"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="none" value="yes"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Actually I got another checkboxes below, it disable others too in another div.How to  enable others?

Comment: modify the expression used in `querySelectorAll` to include the table: ie: `let col=document.querySelectorAll('table input[ type="checkbox" ]:not( [ name="none" ] )');` If the `"other"` checkboxes are also in a table of their own then you need to further clarify the scope of the query expression - without seeing the fullcode it's a little hard to say definitively

Comment: @Amirul Make this as the correct answer if it solved your problem :|

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS solution:

- add id= to controlling checkbox
- add class=dohidepotentially to controlled table rows
- add css style: `#none:checked + table .dohidepotentially {display: none}`

Only downside is that the controlling checkbox must be put *before* the table (for the css neighbouring selector). But it can be hidden.

Shortened example:

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="none" value="yes" id="none">
    <table>
        <tr class="dohidepotentially">
            <td width="100px">2. Sore Throat</td><td width="80px"><input type="hidden" name="sakit_tekak" value="no"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="sore_throat" value="yes"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100px">3. Fever</td><td width="80px"><input type="hidden" name="fever" value="no"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="fever" value="yes"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="230px">5. None of above</td><td width="80px"><input type="hidden" name="none" value="tiada"><label for="none">[click here]</label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You can also hide just the checkboxes, not the rows: `#none:checked + table .dohidepotentially input {display: none;} `

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<table id="sickness">
```

JS

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementById("sickness").getElementsByTagName("input");

var names = ["cough", "sore_throat", "fever","flu"]; 

checkboxes.namedItem("none").addEventListener("change", function(e){
     if(this.checked == true){
         for(var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
             checkboxes.namedItem(names[i]).disabled = true;
         }
     }else{
         for(var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
             checkboxes.namedItem(names[i]).disabled = false;
         }
     }
});
```